# Scatter 3d overlaid on the surface or wireframe plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have 10,000 x, y, z points with 20 of them are as follow, lets called it as data A.

```
0.242745297 0.970090058 0
0.891863203 0.452305209 0.000157095
0.382557235 0.923931742 0.000314191
0.988602615 0.150547827 0.000471286
0.990418256 0.138098816 0.000628381
0.985286122 0.170911207 0.000785477
0.813594577 0.581431832 0.000942572
0.072447325 0.997371634 0.001099667
0.442898837 0.896570712 0.001256762
0.390410171 0.92063994  0.001413858
0.94424855  0.32922972  0.001570953
0.823242628 0.567687052 0.001728048
0.951142253 0.308747244 0.001885143
0.834598707 0.550854633 0.002042238
0.9551501   0.296113912 0.002199333
0.466621761 0.884453831 0.002356428
0.399454286 0.916749669 0.002513523
0.847106351 0.53141669  0.002670618
0.998468109 0.05525793  0.002827712
0.559509437 0.828818606 0.002984807
```

Now, I also have much much less data, called data B, with the same number of column, x y z, as follow:

```
1.09E-16    1.785718947 0
0.019294497 0.30674191  1.118939202
0.077017367 0.913349082 0.621713321
0.402044713 1.391556608 0.01362025
0.274220861 1.67026197  0
0.923642324 0.313530314 0.424167555
1.022371899 0.301758616 0.062661655
1.27727567  0.4131242   0
0.192434487 1.217507707 0.061631979
0.287144078 1.114175886 0.294906802
0.56787764  1.186676548 0.004689697
0.143854651 1.058776687 0.427695299
7.32E-17    1.19517985  0.624420229
0.297763481 1.017599598 0.407829845
0.201402889 1.205216298 0.383356118
0.379563712 0.598453545 0.78331148
0.399108958 0   1.121468066
1.015175114 0.108070734 0.074322688
1.08251008  0   0.241371942
0.240891894 0.739967202 0.710831521
```

Now, I want to plot something like this:
[Data A looks like a sphere or wireframe, and on top of that is data B]

[image: img1]

I have tried something like this:

```
plot3d(dataA, type = "wire")
par(new=TRUE)
plot3d(datab, type = "p")
```

but it did not look like the one that I wanted.

Comment: Please add a relevant language tag by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36817033/edit) the question...

Comment: Hi Matt,
Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I didn't get any points with type='wire'. Looks like it requires a specific mesh3d class of object.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I also cant make a plot with those commands. mesh3d? Can you have an example of that?